# Horizontal scrolling layout LEFT/RIGHT: jQuery/CSS quiz

Tags: jquery, layout, scroll, usability, horizontal-scrolling

It seems, that what I am trying to achieve is almost impossible.

I am trying to create a **horizontal layout** dependant on jQuery, but usable even with Javascript being turned off. I also want the cleanest code possible with its semantic value kept. So I guess I'm looking to the ultimate solution. :)

The most common horizontal layout on the web is this: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html - This would be perfect (it works even with JS being turned off). My problem is I need to make it work "both ways" (left and right with "starting" item in the middle).

The effect should be similar as this: http://steveandjacqs.com/ The website (and the coding backend) is great, but it is unusable without JS and the code is full of hacks.

My CSS:

```
html,body { overflow: hidden; }
.wrapper { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; } 
.wrapper-cont { position: relative; width: 500%; height: 100%; margin-left: -200%; }
#item-left { position: absolute: top: 0px; left: 0%; }
#item-home { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 200%; }
#item-right{ position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 400%; }
#item-down { position: absolute; top: 200%; left: 0%; }
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<nav><ul>
     <li><a href="#item-left">Left</a></li>
     <li><a href="#item-home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#item-right">Right</a></li>
     <li><a href="#item-down">Down</a></li>
</ul></nav>
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="wrapper-cont">
           <div id="item-left">Element outside viewport on the left side</div>
           <div id="item-home">Element on the center of viewport</div>
           <div id="item-right">Element outside viewport on the right side</div>
           <div id="item-down">Element on the center of viewport but down</div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My JAVASCRIPT will use some sort of smooth animation plugin (scrollTo maybe?) between the sections. Browser scrolling (at least vertical) should be disabled, the DIVs itselves should be scrollable.

///

Should I post screenshot of my website or is it understanble this way?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I am more or less jQuery copypasta, so go easy on me please. :)

## UPDATE

What about modifying .htaccess to add internal link on entering the homepage: to rewrite "http://example.com" to "http://example.com#home"? Than I can code the layout "the common way" (such as in previous example from Queness).

Comment: Do you want the menu to stay fixed ? or go with the home item ?

Comment: It should go with home item. I may change that later honestly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to follow the way the example site uses.

The problems in you current setup are

- The menu is not inside the home element, so it does not scroll with it..
- You have wrong dimensions/positions for each "*page*"

To auto-scroll to the `#item-home` on start, you could use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='#item-home'">
```

in the `<head>` section of your page

---

Demo including these corrections/additions at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/QsQDK/1/

Comment: Thank you very much Gaby! Right now I am testing your sollution which appears perfect on JsFiddle. 

First question: After adding `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='#item-home'">`, the page keeps refreshing. 

How to add `"#item-home"` just on first load an prevent refresh?

Comment: hmm... in my system only chrome exhibits this problem.. not sure there is a non-js client workaround. You might need to do what you suggested in your question. That is: rewrite the url to add the `#item-home` fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not over ... My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cibulka/en9sw/7/ It uses plugin ScrollTo from Ariel Flesler for smooth scroll.

Without Javascript, the sollution above works. WITH Javascript it does not. 

The issue is in container that should be scrolled. If I scroll whole document, it works - but than I would have to remove `overflow: hidden`.

Any ideas how to improve the layout? THANK YOU, this is just became unbearable.

Comment: @PetrCibulka, I have made a series of corrections to your code.. (*we had the sizes calculated wrong again*) and the plugin was not working correct, so i made a simple one.. see http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/en9sw/15/

Comment: @PetrCibulka, small correction, make the initial `var currentTarget` to be `var currentTarget = '#home';` so that the resize works correctly even before clicking an option..

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for all the work! After I incorporate some minor additions to the code, I will post a link to final layout (someone might find it useful). If you will be up to give me some feedback to final result, I would be amazed!