# Horizontal and other directional scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to achieve a horizontal scroll with the main content on a center div, but the links go left and right.

```
<div id="left">
Scrolls left
</div>

<div id="home">
Opens on this
</div>

<div id="right">
Scrolls right
</div>
```

I found a stackoverflow  that is kind of talking about the same thing, but using their solutions isnt helping me. Also it was in 2012. I am hoping that we have better methods to do it now. 
[Horizontal scrolling layout LEFT/RIGHT: jQuery/CSS quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683211/horizontal-scrolling-layout-left-right-jquery-css-quiz)

The effect I would probably want to achieve would be the same as 
http://steveandjacqs.com/

Is there any guidance on this?
http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/en9sw/15/

**EDIT:**

I basically want the website to open on #home and go to #left when i hit a link that directs to it..(so it will scroll left when the link is clicked)

Comment: Can you please provide more code, those `div`s in the post are not moving anywhere.

Comment: Yes they arent going anywhere, but I have provided the links of what I tried and attempted. The stackoverflow thread that ive linked is the only attempt close to what I want to achieve but I cant make it work on chrome.. and it breaks

Comment: do you mean something like overflow in css?

Comment: "Blocked content" at jsFiddle, never seen before... Anyway, please add your code to the question, so that we can see what actually breaks. Nobody wants to surf around to find out what you actually need.

Comment: The blocked content turns up because the chrome breaks the code and keeps refreshing, anyway here is his edited fiddle and this does seem to work for me either, http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/en9sw/15/

Comment: I would actually prefer if someone knows how to tackle the result I am looking for than further exploring this broken solution..

Comment: Seems to work in FF, and even in IE. Still, it's better to add the code to the question.

Comment: You can use jquery with the scrollLeft when you click a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this one for you http://jsfiddle.net/medda86/YbW92/

html

```
<div class="left">Scrolls left</div>
<div class="right">Scrolls right</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="page">test1</div>
    <div class="page">Home opens on this</div>
    <div class="page">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. But what I was trying to achieve is the home would be the center div, so home! -- with links left and right.. Left scrolls left.. and right to right..

Comment: You're welcome... Yeah you can modify it with centering your home div and load it like that... And create own events for you left and right links.

Comment: btw, you mean scrolling the content inside the centerdiv or scrolling the whole page?

Comment: I dont know Jquery enough to custom code. I am really new to it.

Comment: Whole page.. see this site? http://steveandjacqs.com/ it opens at the center home div. but it has a div on the left and the right and the bottom .. I cant figure out how he achieved this

Comment: @user2861086 They seem to use [this small plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.fi/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: Perfect! but I dont want the "right link" to just go to the next right div. If I had to link the divs based or anchor tags in the page? like right(on the nav) goes to div "test3" like normal navigation function.. except that in this case I would need one to go left scroll and the other to right scroll .. Thanks so much for helping me..

Comment: Medda, there is still an issue, because in this case the left and right links act as prev and next buttons. but in my case I want them to be a navigation to a particular anchor on the page like on this http://steveandjacqs.com/ site.. so each link will scroll to its section. but the home div is the one in the middle and theres one section before home that scrolls left. and one section after home that scrolls right.

Comment: Actually in retrospect your code does do exactly what the example site does. But is there a way I could directly tke my user to section 3 without having to scroll to home again? 
The code does work on my code, im just confused :(

Comment: That works better! does this automatically make each section equal height, because my left div has  longer content, and so it adds length to my homediv :(

Comment: yeah it does every section same height... I updated and added the scrolltop:0 so it scrolls back to top when you go to another div.

Comment: Hi @Medda86 how are you doing? Thanks for your help with this I have the website up and running since the time you helped me back in 2014. I have however had a weird glitch. On most computers the first time - it shows up from the LEFT slide first and only when refreshed it opens at CENTER slide. 

do you happen to know how to fix that ???